# can I implement notification from backend on flutter app without using firebase?Also how can I navigate to a specific page while clicking notification

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

can I implement notification system from backend on flutter app without using firebase?
What will be the cost, if I use firebase?
does the cost change depend on number of users?
Also how can I navigate to a specific page while clicking notification?

I heard that it is nessessary to link every app to firebase to send personalised notification.

Comment: Yes you can implement notification without firebase . There are many platform but in mostly platform you have to pay for that service. Firebase notification is free of cost and there are no limitation for users. For notification handling please refer this documentation https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As far as I know it is not possible because firebase sends notification directly to platform specific transport layer, I don't know how it can be done with backend - anyways you have to use third-party for that.
2. FCM is totally free
3. Yes you have to register app via app id in firebase console and then you may receive notification either by subscribing topic or generating device token.